# ¿Cómo guardar los resultados de una variable en un ciclo for, en cada iteración del ciclo for?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Esté es el código:

```
N=int(input())
cd=0
j=0

for i in range(N):
  j+=cd
  cp=float(input())
  cd=(cp*(i+1))-j
  print(cd)
```

y quiero imprimir el valor de `cd` cuando `i=0`,`i=1`,...,`i=N-1`. Pero sin usar listas, ni definiendo funciones.

He intentado definir una variable r_i en el bucle, y después imprimirla, pero no ha servido.

**Ejemplo:**

**Como funciona al ejecutarse:**

**Input and Output**

`5, 10, 10, 12, 14, 12, 12, 13, 16, 12.6, 11`

**Como quiero que funcione:**

**Input**

`5, 10, 12, 12, 13, 12.6`

**Output**

`10, 14, 12, 16, 11`

Comment: En tu código no imprimes nada. ¿Cómo estás intentando mostrar en la salida algo y por qué dices que no ha servido? Errores? Datos incorrectos? Por favor [edit] tu pregunta e indica esta información, por favor

Comment: @Alfabravo quiero imprimir 'cd', si pongo print(cd), me imprime el último valor que tomó cd en el ciclo for, es decir, con i=N-1, y quiero imprimir no solo el valor que tomo en i=N-1, sino también con i=1, i=2 ,i=3 etc.

Comment: El `print(cd)` ponlo dentro del `for` es decir, con la misma indentación. Actualmente lo tienes fuera del `for` y por eso imprime únicamente el último valor

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Si así imprime la variable 'cd' con todos los valores de i, pero no es como quiero que salga, por ejemplo quiero que primero se digiten los datos de entrada y luego imprima los datos de salida correspondientes, en lugar de: pedir dato de entrada, luego de salida, luego otra vez dato de entrada, dato de salida y así sucesivamente

Comment: Por favor, EDITA. LA. PREGUNTA. No hay forma más fácil de que nos expliques cómo quieres algo que EN la pregunta. Se ve muuucho mejor que acá abajo. Por favor, por favorcito. Mira que ya tienes dos amigos intentando ayudarte. Permite que te ayuden. Añade lo que intentas decirnos; el editor de la pregunta permite que le des formato a lo que quieres obtener y te van a ayudar muuucho más rápido